Looking for a movie from before 2008 about a car accident
So I saw this movie where in the beginning there was (probably) a couple and they've had a car accident. If my memory isn't wrong, the accident took place near woods on a sand road, it wasn't a typical street or a highway. 
Then it seems like the life was going normally but in the end it looked like it was all a dream or a vision before they died. So basically the beginning and the end show this car with those people. 
I think it was something between a horror and a thriller but I can't remember anything else and I'd really like to watch this movie again. Does anyone have any ideas?

My first thought on reading this was Vanilla Sky.

Don't quite match but may be Dead End or Reeker, both had a similar ending.

I was going to comment under your question, but I must have 50 reputation first... The movie you described sounds like The Butterfly Effect 2.
EDIT:

Julie and her boyfriend, Nick, are celebrating Julie's 24th birthday with their friends Trevor and Amanda...
... As the four friends drive back to the city there's an accident with a semi-truck.
One year later, Nick suffers a blinding headache and nosebleed at work, while presenting an important sales pitch to investors. As a result he is given a week's suspension. Back home, Nick looks at photographs from Julie's birthday and somehow manages to transport himself back to the moment just before the fatal accident.

Source: Wikipedia

Can you please expand on this? Explain why you think this matches the description?
